Keystone-6 Session issue on refresh. Session token is not valid after refresh

Recently updated to @keystone-6/core@^6.1.0 and facing this issue token is not valid after any entry in list or page refresh.



const { withAuth } = createAuth({
  listKey: 'User',
  identityField: 'phone',
  sessionData: 'name id email phone userType',
  secretField: 'password',
  initFirstItem: {
    fields: ['name', 'phone', 'password'],
  },
});
const sessionMaxAge = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
const session = statelessSessions({
  maxAge: sessionMaxAge,
  secret: sessionSecret!,
});

export { withAuth, session };

Already have session secret in env file.




You might need to expand on your description so people can assist. So you can sign into the Admin UI but then any time you refresh the page your token expires? What's the exact error you get? Does dropping back to v5.8.0 resolve the issue? Screenshots might help, and maybe information on the actual HTTP requests being made from your browser dev tools.
